# Why isn't this code working? C++

Tags: c++

This code should ask the user for a their name and then split it at the space.

It should put the firstname in the variable first, and the last name in de variable lastname

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char string[80];
char first[20];
char lastname[20];
bool f = true;
int c = 0;
cout << "Whats your Name? \n";
gets(string);

for(int i =0; i < strlen(string); i++){
    if(string[i] == ' ') {
        f = false;
        c = 0;
    }

    if(f) {
        first[c] = string[i];
    } else if(!f) {
        lastname[c] = string[i];
    }


    c++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(first); i++) {
    cout << first[i] << "\n";
}
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(lastname); i++) {
    cout << lastname[i]<< "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is happening showing any exception?

Comment: If you are doing this in C++ don't use `char*` instead use `std::string` then you can use `find_first_of` to find the first space split it.

Comment: Define **Not Working**.

Comment: Is printing the names "vertically" deliberate? **Never** use `gets`. It's inherently unsafe.

Comment: Just to mention the alternative, use `fgets`.

Comment: This is an example of strongly C-flavoured C++

Comment: thanks, the problem was that it is was printing strang characthers. I'm just starting C++ and coming from c# and php. And the string/char thing is pritty new to me. Thanks for the anwsers. I am going to look up some string librarys next.

Comment: comming from c# the code looked fine in my eyes

Comment: +1 just to counter the negative vote.

Comment: You should avoid overriding class names with local variables `string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you really need to write this using only C functions, it would be much easier to use C++ strings.

Something like (this is untested):

```
std::string input;
std::string first;
std::string lastname;

// prompt the user
std::cout << "What's your name? ";
// get a line of input
std::getline(std::cin, input);

// find a space in the string
size_t space = input.find_first_of(" ");
// was the space found?
if (space != std::string::npos)
{
    // copy out the first and last names
    first = input.substr(0, space);
    lastname = input.substr(space + 1);

    // output them to stdout
    std::cout << first << std::endl << lastname << std::endl;
}
```

This means you don't have to worry about null-terminating strings or string lengths or anything like that. As flolo said, your code doesn't do that and thus will definitely run into problems. The memory layout of a C string is an array of characters with a null byte on the end, which is how things like strlen() know where the end of the string is. Also, your code's going to have a horrible time the moment somebody enters a name with more than 20 characters in it, which isn't particularly implausible.

Answer (score 1):

You dont say how your program does behave wrong. But one error I see is due to the fact that c-strings are 0-terminated. You must add in your "if ...==" a `first[c]=0;` (before you reset c to 0) and after the the loop a `lastname[c]=0`.

Comment: ... one should add why this is important: `strlen(first)` and `strlen(lastname)` will fail when the 0-terminator is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Talk about doing things the hard way.  It would be easier using
`std::string`, but if you insist on using `char[]`, don't use `gets`
(which is irremdially broken), but `fgets`, and second, find the end of 
the string once and for all.  So either (preferred:

```
std::string line;
std::getline( std::cin, line );
if ( ! std::cin )
    //  Something when wrong...
typedef std::string::const_iterator Iter;
Iter begin = line.begin();
Iter end = line.end();
```

or:

```
char line[80];
if (fgets( line, stdin ) == NULL )
    //  Something went wrong...
typedef char const* Iter;
Iter begin = line;
Iter end = line + strlen( line );
if ( end != begin && *(end - 1) == '\n' )
    --end;
```

Then find the first space:

```
Iter pivot = std::find( begin, end, ' ' );
```

Then create the two strings first and last, either:

```
std::string first( begin, pivot );
std::string last( pivot == end ? end : pivot + 1 );
```

or

```
char first[80] = { '\0' };  //  nul fill to ensure trailing '\0'
std::copy( begin, pivot, first );
char last[80] = { '\0' };
std::copy( pivot == end ? end : pivot + 1, end, last );
```

Then output:

```
std::cout << first << std::endl;
std::cout << last << std::endl;
```

Of course, if you're using `std::string`, you don't even need to create
the variables `first` and `last`; you can output a temporary:

```
std::cout << std::string( begin, pivot ) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::string( pivot == end ? end : pivot + 1, end ) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some minor issues not mentioned from the others:

```
    if(f) {
        first[c] = string[i];
    } else if(!f) { // <- this "if" statement looks like you did not understand "if .. else"
        lastname[c] = string[i];
    }
```

So better write:

```
    if(f) {
        first[c] = string[i];
    } else { 
        lastname[c] = string[i];
    }
```

And the part

```
 if(string[i] == ' ') {
        f = false;
        c = 0;
 }
```

should be better

```
 if(string[i] == ' ') {
        f = false;
        c = 0;
        continue;
 }
```

because otherwise your `lastname` will always contain a leading space.